# Assign data to view in cakephp 3.6

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cakephp 1.1 we can use $this->data = array(value), so in ctp file, control (input, checkbox, ...) can received data automatically.
How can i do the same in cakephp 3.6?
I have try some solution but they don't work.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 3.6, you can use Controller set method to pass data on the ctp file

```
Cake\Controller\Controller::set(string $var, mixed $value)
```

> The Controller::set() method is the main way to send data from your
>   controller to your view. Once you’ve used Controller::set(), the
>   variable can be accessed in your view:

```
$form = $this->Model->get($id); // to get data from the database
$this->set('form', $form); // to pass data on the ctp file
```

Then you can directly pass to your form to automatically detect data:

```
$this->Form->create($form);
```

[CakePhp -> Controllers -> Setting View Variables](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#setting-view-variables)